# Open a Component with same Datasource again with Lifecycle Hook(ngOnChanges)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with the lifecycle hook ngOnChanges. If I want to call up different data sets, it works wonderfully, but this doesn't work if I want to call up the same data set again but nothing has changed. Is there a solution for this? If so, what does it look like?

Greetings Tobias

Comment: `ngOnChanges` is triggered when the inputs of a component are changed. The parameter is of type `SimpleChanges`, which contains bothe the previous values of the inputs and their current values. Please phrase your question better and provide a [mcve] showing your issue.

Comment: as OnChanges specify, it is meant for changes in props only. If there are some changes done, which your component has not recognized, you can use `ChangeDetectorRef` and force the change detection. Do not use it for fetching the data.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I'll try to explain it a little better.

I have filled a Devextreme DataGrid with data sets and now I want to retrieve the individual information such as master data etc.
The respective details for the individual data record are summarized in a component and then called up and displayed.

If I change the data sets and then call up the respective details, ngOnChanges works wonderfully. But if I close the details of the record and want to call it up again, the ngOnChanges doesn't work anymore.

Comment: But I don't want to constantly call up another data set first, I want to call up this one again straight away.